# Error posting to Slack - Docker jenkins unable to find valid certificate

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssl-certificate, slack, keytool

My jenkins is running through `docker-compose` (Hosted as per this [Link](https://dev.to/andresfmoya/install-jenkins-using-docker-compose-4cab)). I am trying to integrate `jenkins` with `slack` through`Slack Notification Plugin -2.45`. Below is the snapshot of my slack configuration enabled in jenkins.

[image: Jenkins Slack Configuration]

`Test Connection` always returns `Failure`. Below `ssl certificate error` found in Jenkins `System Log` section.

```
Error posting to Slack
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
```

My docker-container image is having below `java version`

```
# docker exec -it jenkins java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

I have no problem in installing new plugins from `Plugin Manager` with `https` protocol.

To fix the certificate error i have changed `https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json` to `http` but still same problem persists.

Our Network proxy team confirmed that access to `slack.com:443` already allowed.

How do i resolve this issue in my `docker-jenkins`? any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created `dockerfile` with `COPY ./cacerts /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/` command, Now Jenkins and Slack connection works.